# codesign --deep on mavericks xcode 5.0 (5A1412)

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, osx-mavericks, codesign

I am using `codesign` with `—deep` option.

[image]

```
/usr/bin/codesign --verbose --force --sign "Developer ID Application: myCompany” —deep myApp.app
```

on 10.8 its working fine

```
$ codesign -vvv myApp.app
myApp.app: valid on disk
myApp.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

But on 10.9 i am getting `nested code is modified or invalid`.

```
$ codesign -vvv myApp.app
myApp.app: nested code is modified or invalid
file modified: myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/SecondUtility
```

I have two executable in MacOS folder, one is from build phase(Destination: executables)

```
$codesign -vvv myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/SecondUtility
myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/SecondUtility: valid on disk
myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/SecondUtility: does not satisfy its designated Requirement
```

[Run Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHGga.png) with the code sign shell command is also not working for me.

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: I do not see the `--deep` option in your first command line.

Comment: copy paste problem. I am using --deep in other code signing flags.

Comment: See: http://furbo.org/2013/10/17/code-signing-and-mavericks/

Comment: Run Script with code sign command doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After creating build in Xcode 5, again code sign SecondUtility and myApp.app.

```
sudo /usr/bin/codesign --verbose --force --sign "Developer ID Application: myCompany" myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/SecondUtility

sudo /usr/bin/codesign --verbose --force --sign "Developer ID Application: myCompany" myApp.app
```

Now its working fine.

Run Script with the code sign shell command is not working for me.

**EDIT**

Have a look at [OS X Code Signing In Depth](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG205)

Beginning with OS X version 10.9.5, there will be changes in how OS X recognizes signed apps

[Structure your bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkAnatomy.html) according to the expectations for OS X version 10.9 or later:

- Only include signed code in directories that should contain signed
  code.
- Only include resources in directories that should contain
  resources.
- Do not use the --resource-rules flag or    ResourceRules.plist. They
  have been obsoleted and will be rejected.

Comment: For some reason this only works when I sign the root app first then sign the `SecondUtility`.

Comment: @ThomasReggi From my experience with Yosemite, it is the opposite.

Comment: @Parag Bafna I your commands with Xcode 6 on Yosemite, the codesign itself seems to pass. But the verification says "nested code modified or invalid." And the app, if downloaded through HTTP, is seen as "damaged".

Comment: How we can trust to that sign key? I've signed my app with that, but whenever I run it and wants to do its stuff, OS says: "MyApp is trying to install a new helper tool". and when I insert the password, it asks again and again!